# Batch convert multiple PDF to Image on Mac

Tags: images, pdf, conversion, batch, jpeg

What would be the quickest way to convert a bunch of pdf files to jpeg files?  I know I can open Preview and Save As image, but that could take a long time.

Comment: see my answer [http://superuser.com/questions/68805/free-program-tool-to-convert-multiple-images-into-a-single-pdf/605160#605160](http://superuser.com/questions/68805/free-program-tool-to-convert-multiple-images-into-a-single-pdf/605160#605160)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Automator has a "Render PDF Pages to Images" action. Under Snow Leopard and El Capitan, there's a wizard that pops up when you run Automator asking you to choose a template. The second template is "Application":

> Applications are self-running
>   workflows. Any files or folders
>   dropped onto an Application will be
>   used as input to the workflow.

So:

- Open Automator
- Choose "Application"
- Drag the "Render PDF Pages to Images" action onto the workflow
- This action produces random filenames, so follow it with "Rename Finder Items" (choose "Make sequential" from the dropdown list(you can skip this action in Sierra as it no longer exists and it just uses original file name)
- Then add a "Move Finder Items" to have the output files moved to the Desktop (You can click on the "desktop" and choose a different location for the output files to go)
- Save your new application somewhere (I suggest saving to the desktop makes it easy for drag and drop)
- Drag files onto it
- Enjoy.

Comment: Hmm...I tried it, but where does the output file go?  I don't see anything.

Comment: The help text for the action (lower-left corner of Automator) has a note saying that the output files are randomly named - "this action is often followed by the Rename Finder Items -> Make Sequential" action.

I did that, and added a "Move finder items" to move them to the Desktop as well.

Sorry for being unclear - I've added these steps into the list of actions.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me... I launch the app and it just hangs and does nothing.

Comment: @joe - That's correct. You're not meant to launch the workflow, you just drag-and-drop the files onto the icon

Comment: How would you make it save the file in place, instead of to a specified folder such as the desktop?

Answer (score 0):

How about [pdf2jpg](http://www.versiontracker.com/dyn/moreinfo/macosx/17982)?

> PDF2JPG is a droplet based application
>   for converting **any number of files you
>   drop on it** into either JPG or PNG
>   format, also allows you to select
>   compression level when converting to
>   JPG. This application requires that
>   you have the ImageMagick libraries
>   installed from [Fink](http://www.finkproject.org/). Information on
>   installing ImageMagick and, if needed,
>   Fink as well.

Comment: Link is dead! :(