# Convert PDF to images (windows)

Tags: windows, drivers, images, pdf, conversion

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How do I save an image PDF file as an image?](https://superuser.com/questions/49099/how-do-i-save-an-image-pdf-file-as-an-image)
>   [How to print documents to pictures (gif, bmp etc.) on windows](https://superuser.com/questions/35590/how-to-print-documents-to-pictures-gif-bmp-etc-on-windows)

Windows.

What's the best free tool to convert PDF to images?

I would even prefer to have printer driver able to print to images directly.

Comment: Mention your system http://superuser.com/questions/49099/how-do-i-save-an-image-pdf-file-as-an-image http://superuser.com/questions/88379/batch-convert-multiple-pdf-to-image-on-mac

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/35590/how-to-print-documents-to-pictures-gif-bmp-etc-on-windows

Answer (score 1):

on windows http://en.pdfforge.org/pdfcreator is able to print to .pngs, .jpgs etc.